# How can I create button which clears an EditText?

Tags: android

How can I create a button which resets/deletes all text in an `EditText`.

This is some code I've written:

```
private View.OnClickListener onRes =new View.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Here i wanna put some code to clear the EditText

    }
};
```

I don't have any idea how to do that.

Comment: suggest you to google net ,this forum a bit before asking basic question. you will get answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one `EditText`, something like a form and you would like to have a reset button that resets all fields then I suggest you create an `ArrayList` which holds all your `EditText` widgets.

Once your reset button is pressed just iterate over the list and clear every field. Here is an example:

```
// Your already defined EditText widgets.
List<EditText> fieldList = new ArrayList<EditText>();

fieldList.add(editText1);
fieldList.add(editText2);
// and so on

public void onClick(View v) {
    for (EditText field : fieldList) {
        field.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Set the listener to your `Button` :

```
Button resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
resetButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

2) Let your `Activity` implements the `OnClickListener` :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
```

3) Override the method `onClick` like this :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v ) {

EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt);
txt.setText("");

}
```

Comment: thanks mate. 
 private View.OnClickListener onRes =new View.OnClickListener(){
  
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   EditText jalan = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.jalan);
   EditText kota = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kota);
   EditText postal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.post);
   
   jalan.setText(" ");
   kota.setText(" ");
   postal.setText(" ");
   
  }
 };

Comment: Yes that's it , and if you have a looot of EditText , you can use an ArrayList to store them in an Array as @Octavian Damiean have explained on his answer. if it works with you , accept the answer sos others can get informations from it.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    myEditText.setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

basically i aggree with the answers from @benyamin.
i used it to my own android applications.

with a method

```
setText("")
```

it will give a null string to your EditText properties.

this is the code on my own application with basically used the answers from benyamin

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    myEditText.setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btnabout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);

btnabout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View V) 
    {
         txtText.setText(""); 
    } //end onClick         
}); //end button
```